# Tensorflow: RBF Net for measuring speed of a fluid in a tub over microphone

Tags: performance, tensorflow, audio, artificial-intelligence

I need a plan to bulid a RBF net over tensorflor to measure th speed of a flluid in a tub over a microphone.

Plan is to make training samples of sound with th corresponding fluid speed.

In use  the flow of sound samples should be evalualted to the actual speed

nothing so far. i am rying to build the code with tensorflow